# What is the music that plays in Bleach Episode 46 ~19:54

Tags: music, bleach

Can you guys tell me what the name of the music that plays in Bleach episode 46 around 19:54. When Aizen and Ichimaru arrive to save the students from hollows. I love this song and can't find the name on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

It's called 
**BL_16 (Reminiscence - "Bankai... Senbonzakura Kageyoshi")**

Although it is sometimes also known as **Destiny Awaits - Bankai Version**

As with most music in Bleach, it is composed by Shiro Sagisu.

It can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ei5UmDyB0i4

Comment: Would you happen to know which album this track is from?

Comment: It's from the Bleach Anime 5th Anniversary Boxset, Bonus CD 1